# How to pass jinja2 variable to json_query

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template, json-query

I have the following jinja2 template

```
[
{% for items in hosts %}
{
    "name":"{{ items.name }}",
    "display_name":"{{ items.display_name }}",
    "services": {{ host_group | from_json | json_query('[*].services[0]') | to_json }},
}
{% endfor %}
]
```

i need to replace **services[0]** by a variable **{{ loop.index0 }}**, i tried this syntax

```
"services": {{ host_group | from_json | json_query('[*].services[loop.index0]') | to_json }}
```

but i'm getting an error :

```
AnsibleFilterError: JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:
    Expecting: star, got: unquoted_identifier: Parse error at column 13, token "loop" (UNQUOTED_IDENTIFIER), for expression:
    "[*].services[loop.index0]"
```

I tried another syntax:

```
"services": {{ host_group | from_json | json_query('[*].services[' + {{ loop.index0 }} +']') | to_json }},
```

and it gives also an error :

```
AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: [
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to keep in mind when working with Jinja:

1. You never nest the `{{...}}` template markers.
2. If you put something in quotes, it's a literal string.

So when you write:

```
json_query('[*].services[loop.index0]')
```

You are passing `json_query` the *literal string* `[*].services[loop.index0]`, which isn't a valid JMESPath query. If you want to substitute the value of a variable in a string, you need to either build the string via concatenation, or use string formatting logic.

### Concatenation

Using concatenation might look like:

```
json_query('[*].services[' ~ loop.index0 ` ']')
```

Here, `~` is the string concatenation operator -- it's like `+`, but it makes sure to convert everything into a string. Compare this:

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a 'msg={{ "there are " + 4 + " lights" }}'
```

To this:

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a 'msg={{ "there are " ~ 4 ~ " lights" }}'
```

### String formatting

Using string formatting might look like:

```
json_query('[*].services[%s]' % (loop.index0))
```

Or:

```
json_query('[*].services[{}]'.format(loop.index0))
```

These are two forms of string formatting available in Python; for more details, start [here](https://pyformat.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Using Ansible `2.9.23`.

For the string placeholders `{}` and `%s` I had to use backticks, otherwise it wouldn't work:

```
json_query('results[?name==`{}`].version'.format(query))
json_query('results[?name==`%s`].version' % (query))
```

Given the example json:

```
{
    (...)
    "results": [
        {
            "envra": "0:ntp-4.2.6p5-29.el7_8.2.x86_64",
            "name": "ntp",
            "repo": "installed",
            "epoch": "0",
            "version": "4.2.6p5",
            "release": "29.el7_8.2",
            "yumstate": "installed",
            "arch": "x86_64"
        },
        (...)
    ],
    (...)
}
```

created by:

```
- name: list installed packages
  yum:
    list: installed
  register: installed_list
```

with a defined variable `query: ntp`, pass this variable to `json_query` in two ways:

```
- name: pass var to json_query - string formatting (1)
  debug:
    msg: "{{ installed_list|json_query('results[?name==`{}`].version'.format(query))|first }}"

- name: pass var to json_query - string formatting (2)
  debug:
    msg: "{{ installed_list|json_query('results[?name==`%s`].version' % (query))|first }}"
```

Results:

```
TASK [pass var to json_query - string formatting (1)] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": "4.2.6p5"
}

TASK [pass var to json_query - string formatting (2)] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": "4.2.6p5"
}
```